# Option key not working for switching in bootcamp. MacOS boot volume not in windows partition

Tags: bootcamp, windows

When I restart the computer (a 2016 15-inch Touch-Bar MacBook Pro running 10.14.4 Mojave) and hold down the option key, the computer just boots into macOS. It does not access that "switching" screen. How can this be fixed?

Yes: I have reset the NVRAM multiple times

Yes: I can still manually boot in to windows through startup disk. The problem arises when I load into windows 10 and it can't boot back into the Mac portion because windows can't load the Mac OS boot volume.

The Mac portion recognizes the windows portion perfectly fine, but not vice versa.

**UPDATE:** I think its keyboard related.

Comment: How are you switching from Window back to macOS? Are you stuck in Windows?

Comment: I am in Mac now. Loaded into windows, almost got stuck in it, reset NVRAM and managed to boot back in. Do not want to have to go through it every single time to switch. When I reset NVRAM on the Mac portion again, it doesn't work.

Comment: I think there are 2 separate issues here - Switching back from Win to Mac is a known issue [& often the only solution to which is the opt key...], so try figure out the opt key issue first, as that's the one killing your workflow. First thing I'd try is an external keyboard, preferably a real Apple one, USB rather than wireless.